# create a .json file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I'm trying to do a function with JS and nodejs to create a .json file with my MongoDB data in it.

But when I run my function my console show me

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.

I've done some research and my console that writeJsonFile's value is an object with no value, I don't know if it's the cause of my problem

```
json(event){ 
 count = Subs.find({}).count();
  var json;
  var obj;
  Subs.find({}).forEach(function (div) {
    var sub_type = div.type;
    var sub_TO = div.text;
    var man = div.topic;
    obj = {[man]: []};
    obj[man].push({"type": sub_type, "TO": sub_TO});
    json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    const writeJsonFile = require('write-json-file');

    writeJsonFile('foo.json', {foo: true}).then(() => {
      console.log('done');
    });
    console.log(json);
  });
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get this error? And do you still get the error if you remove all code above the json writing part?

Comment: Where do you get this error ? In the `writeJsonFile` function whose code you don't show ?

Comment: @Jerodev the error came at the line `const writeJsonFile = require('write-json-file');` and if i remove the code above i still have the problem

Comment: Is `write-json-file` a third party module, or something you've written in the same folder as that JS code?

Comment: @Andy `write-json-file`is a npm install module that i found here [link] (https://github.com/sindresorhus/write-json-file#writejsonfilesyncfilepath-data-options)

Answer (score 3):

Better you use `fs` module of `nodejs`. No need to install it.

Here simple example of writing data to JSON file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
json = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
}
json = JSON.stringify(json);
fs.writeFile('./foo.json', json, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've install nodejs and copy paste your code but i have an error `fs.writeFile is not a function` (sorry if i'm bad i've never use it)

Comment: the last one 9.2.0

Comment: the function will be in a react app so i use meteor to run my react app

Comment: make one file test.js copy paste my code in that file and do **node test.js**. Is it working or not?